# add relation and parent in single request with flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models in my flask app which uses sql_alchemy

The two models `location` and `message` have a one to many relationship.

```
class LocationModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class MessageModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    location = db.relationship("LocationModel", back_populates="messages")
    content = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, message_id, content):
        self.message_id = message_id
        self.content = content
```

I would like to create an endpoint in the app that allows a user to provide `location_name` and `content` and it then creates a new location using the `name` and a new message using `content` and sets the foreign key `location_id` for `location` as being the id of the new location.

I tried to follow [Inserting new records with one-to-many relationship in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433338/inserting-new-records-with-one-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy)

I created a class method

```
@classmethod
def add_both(cls, name, content):
    l = cls(name)
    m = MessageModel(content=content)
    l.messages.append(m)
    db.session.add(l)
    db.session.add(m)
    db.session.commit()
```

But I get an error because `__init__`  is missing the required `location_id`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `m = MessageModel(content=content, location_id=l)`?